# Why did Goddess Saraswati lift the Sindhu river?

Tags: saraswati, rivers, sindhu

Why did Goddess Saraswati lift the Sindhu river? Please provide the background/context for why the goddess needed to lift the river.

Comment: Can you give a context?

Comment: Please be more specific